# Can I use IndexedDB in my Desktop Web application

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, indexeddb

I have being using typeahead.js in my web application. for those who don't know typeahead is a suggestion library which takes the data from you ajax call and shows its value in a drop down menu like google search engine do. it's quite impressive.

But now I am facing some issue data from ajax call is too heavy so that chrome cache unable to handle such a huge amount data. by going through google. I have found this IndexedDB API.

IndexedDB API which I came to know by googling. It store the data chrome browser offline instead of saving it in cache. please correct me if my understanding is wrong about IndexedDB.

So can I used it to store data client side browser. in my Desktop Web application.

Comment: Yes, you could use indexeddb for store your data locally, but when you say that chrome cache is unable to handle your data I think your are looking in the wrong direction, of how many data are you talking about?

Comment: approx 1 million row

Comment: Whats a desktop web application?

Comment: Firefox has no limit on the IndexedDB database's size. The user interface will just ask permission for storing blobs bigger than 50 MB. This size quota can be customized through the dom.indexedDB.warningQuota preference (which is defined in http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/modules/libpref/src/init/all.js).
Google Chrome: see https://developers.google.com/chrome...rage#temporary

Answer (score 0):

Yes

You may use IndexedDB in your desktop web app, Its recommended especially for storing large JSON's

check out [Progressive Web Apps Training Working with IndexedDB](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-indexeddb)

Comment: Where does that or any link cover IndexedDB in a {‘desktop..app’} -as I see that link covering only pure web-browser uses. But I'm guessing the desktop use would require  I'm guessing via Electron or NW.js or other https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(browser_engine)#Frameworks .

Comment: I'm not sure. sorry